# Remove additive-zero-mean-Gaussian noise

Tags: noise, gaussian, noise-cancellation

I have 5 values, and each value is corrupted by Additive-Zero-Mean-Gaussian Noise with variance = 0.05.

Each value is in the range from 0 to 1. Is there anyway for me to remove the noise?

Comment: Are those 5 values taken from a bigger sample of values? What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Each value is a number from 0 to 1, unfortunately.

Comment: I am trying to find the sum of these 5 values, the denoised version

Comment: I get that, but why? What's the purpose? What's the application? Where are these values coming from?

Comment: Are the 5 values all measurements of the same thing s.t. in a perfect world they would have the same value?